# Ionic: CSS renders differently on Ionic Serve, Android emulator and Android device

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

Building the interface of my Ionic app I have the problem that it renders differently depending on where do you run it. Every time I fix something I end up breaking something else.

Here is how the message inbox I'm developing looks like:

- Ionic serve and Android emulator: http://s17.postimg.org/525i6eg6n/error_buzon.png
- Android device: http://s24.postimg.org/4jtj9gqlh/2015_05_22_16_45_45.png

The HTML code is like this:

```
<ion-view hide-back-button="false" view-title="Buzón de Mensajes" class="buzon-page">
  <!-- <ion-nav-bar> </ion-nav-bar> -->
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-exit" ng-click="cerrarSesion()">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <div class="superior">     
  <div class="list list-inset" >
    <label class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="botones">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-positive">
          Promociones
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-energized" >
          Aprobados
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-assertive" >
          Alerta
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-balanced" >
          ATM
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <ion-content class="lista-contenedor">
    <ion-list class="list">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="mensaje in mensajes" 
        ng-class="mensaje.tipo == 'Promocion' ? 'clasePromocion': 
                  mensaje.tipo == 'Aprobado'  ? 'claseAprobado' : 
                  mensaje.tipo == 'Alerta'    ? 'claseAlerta'   : 
                  mensaje.tipo == 'ATM'       ? 'claseATM'      : 'default'" 
        ng-click="abrirMensaje($index)" 
        on-hold="mostrarMenu(mensaje, $index)"
        item="item"
        class="item-remove-animate">

        <h2><b>{{ mensaje.hid }}</b></h2>
        <h3>{{ mensaje.alert }}</h3>
        <p class="cont">{{ mensaje.mens }}</p>
        <p class="fecha">{{ mensaje.fecha }}</p>

        <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="mostrarMenuComp($index)">
          Compartir
        </ion-option-button>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="mostrarMenuElim($index)">
          Eliminar
        </ion-option-button>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
/* 
  CSS para la pagina Buzon 
*/
/* tercera linea de cada mensaje */
.buzon-page .cont{
  color: gray;
}

/* contenedor de cuadro busqueda y botones */
.buzon-page .superior{
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.buzon-page .list-inset{
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

/* cuadro de busqueda */
.buzon-page label{
  margin-top: 0%;
  border:2px solid #C0C0C0;
}

/* hilera de botones */
.buzon-page .botones{
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

/* cada boton */
.buzon-page .button-block{
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0px;
  border:2px solid;
}

.buzon-page .row, .col{
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.buzon-page .lista-contenedor{
  margin-top: 33%;
}

.item-remove-animate .item-content {
  padding: 15px;
}

.clasePromocion .item-content {
  border-left: solid 6px #0078ff !important; /* azul */
}

.claseAprobado .item-content {
  border-left: solid 6px #faaf40 !important; /* amarillo */
}

.claseAlerta .item-content {
  border-left: solid 6px #ee4036 !important; /* rojo */
}

.claseATM .item-content {
  border-left: solid 6px #00a551 !important; /* verde */
}

.default .item-content {
  border-left: solid 6px white !important; /* blanco por defecto */
}

.buzon-page .fecha{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Obviously the gap in the Android device is because of **.buzon-page .lista-contenedor{ margin-top: 33%; }**. The question is why is it necessary in Ionic Serve and Android emulator and a problem in an actual device? How am I supposed to develop and app like this?

Debugging with Chrome DevTools would be the ideal but I don't have acces to a device with 4.4+ android version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android and iOS have different browsers, and render things slightly different, on some cases you have to work with your CSS to make specific's CSS for Android or iOS.

When you build your app to run on iOS or Android, specific classes are automatically added to the body tag.

- iOS: `<body class="platform-ios">`
- Android: `<body class="platform-android">`
- Web: `<body class="platform-browser">`

Work with those classes to solve your problem. Add them to your CSS to make specific changes.

Comment: Makes no sense, in the Android emulator looks great, but in an Android device it renders a wide empty space for no reason.

Comment: It actually makes sense, some CSS's are added/edited with those classes in the body tag. It also might have somethings to do with your Android version in device beign different from your emulator, which would have a different browsers version, rendering things slightly different. You can debug your app with [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), perhaps you can see something there you are not seeing. Also `.buzon-page .lista-contenedor{
  margin-top: 33%;
}` seems to be adding that space.. Check with Chrome DevTools.

Comment: That would be great if I had Android 4.4 or better, but I don't. And the main question is why do I have to put a 33% margin for some platforms and not for others.

Comment: My answer states exactly why, different platforms, different versions have different browsers which renders different. Platform specific classes are added to your body tag to help you accomplish styles.  Are you even trying with those specific classes? Not everything works out of the box. You don't seem to even try solutions or give me more information. [Isolate specific platforms using CSS in the Ionic framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432360/how-to-isolate-specific-platforms-using-css-selectors-in-the-ionic-framework).

Comment: that's what I call a light answer, good one @Ariel, and by the time you can render your app on the browser inspect it and you will see that IONIC is using "platform-ios" + "platform-browser" classes change the ios to android and you will see the styles that applies on android devices.